# Adding an image in a picture box Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, xna, picturebox

I created a windows form to display text in a richtext and then added a picture box to add some color to it. at the moment when I load up the form it looks like this:

[image: Version Windows Form]

The dot above the rich text is the location of were I added the picture box, at the moment when I try to add an image to picture box it gives me an error: `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: docData.` I get this error by going to the properties of the picture box and to Image witch is labled (none) at the moment.

How do I fix this problem that I am having. (I use C# 2010 Express, XNA Game Studio 4.0, Windows Game(4.0))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a Windows Game (4.0) issue. See the answer on [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3c3ec0cb-c68c-4349-ade7-c00c5285f662/setting-picturebox-initialimage-throws-error?forum=winforms) page. You could try to set the image in your code like this:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("path/somefile.jpg");
```

According to [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/657016/winforms) page, this problem is a bug that hasn't been fixed.

Comment: I had seen that it was a bug and was just hoping that there was a work around. I will try the link and the code above to try and fix the problem. Thank you for the help.